# Replacing if a character comes odd number of times in the begining of a String || Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will look for the number of forward slashes (/) in the beginning of a String and if their are odd number of backslahes they will be replaced by empty String

```
    String regex = "^/(//)*";
    System.err.println("Case1: " +   "/".replaceAll(regex,""));
    System.err.println("Case2: " +   "//".replaceAll(regex,""));
    System.err.println("Case3: " +   "///".replaceAll(regex,""));
    System.err.println("Case4: " +   "/b".replaceAll(regex,""));
    System.err.println("Case5: " +   "//b".replaceAll(regex,""));
    System.err.println("Case6: " +   "///b".replaceAll(regex,""));
```

My regex is working with case 1,3,4 and 6 but in case 2 and 5 it is printing / and /b as output respectively.

Please help.

Comment: So what do you expect exactly? `"/" => ""` and `"//" => "//"` and `"///" => ""`?

Answer (score 3):

Add a negative lookahead `(?!/)` in your regex to check that there is no further `/` after matching the odds. In your case its picking odd number of `/` from the `//` or `///`, hence didn't work.

```
String regex = "^/(//)*(?!/)";
                       ^^^^^ here
```

Comment: Youe beat me to it by a few seconds. +1

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String regex = "^/(//)*(?=[^/]|$)";
```